# When and where should CTCallCenter be released?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, core-telephony

I'm using CTCallCenter to register to call events.

```
CTCallCenter *callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
callCenter.callEventHandler=^(CTCall* call)
{
    if (call.callState == CTCallStateDisconnected)
    { 
        //we know that the call has ended.
        [self phoneCallEnded];
    }
};
```

XCode says it's leaking... Makes sense.

If I release `callCenter` here, the eventHandler is not invoked.

My question is, where and when must i release it? Should I make it a member and release it in `dealloc()`' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it a member as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

use NSAUTORelease Pool. write your code between

```
NSAutoReleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoReleasePool alloc] init];


/////Write Your Code of phone call ended

[pool release];
```